# TypeScript error when using the Function.prototype.call() method

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm getting an error in TypeScript when I try to use the 'call' method to switch out the 'this' reference.  Is there a more 'correct' way to do this that will get rid of the error?

I can distill it down to this code (although I encountered it when doing the tutorial here: http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/privacy-and-publish-subscribe-functions on step 9.10.  Using the code of that tutorial directly from github produces the same problem.

Code to reproduce (in addition to 9.10 in the above tutorial):

```
function testIt(): Object{

    return {};
}

testIt.call(this);
```

Error generated:

```
[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Edit: Note that I'm getting this issue specifically in Visual Studio Code, and others have demonstrated the error does not arise in all environments.

Comment: Where are you doing this call? What is `this`?

Comment: You can see the full context in the tutorial at the link if you like (it is manifesting itself specifically in the `Meteor.publish` calls in 9.10).  That being said - does it matter?  As long as `this` is a valid object, shouldn't the `.call()` method accept any type of `this`?  Also note that it all runs and works as expected, it seems to just by a type error from the Typescript linter.  ...I'll also add that I've tried in various places where `this` refers to different things - same error regardless.

Comment: Hm, I only know that Typescript had (has?) problems with declaring the type of `this` in a method. Maybe `testIt` is a function (not a method) which is expected not to be called on objects? Try `.call(undefined)`

Comment: Your code compiles well for me with no errors, [try it out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20testIt()%3A%20Object%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0A%09fn()%20%7B%0A%09%09testIt.call(this)%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Yup - compiles and generates JavaScript just fine, but Visual Studio Code's linter complains with the provided error.  ...so maybe this is a VS Code issue.  My issue remains but I'll update the tags and original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with version 1.5.2 of VSCode and I'm not getting error, try to update it.

Comment: 1.5.2 here as well, but on OS X.  Problem remains.  The code hint implies that it is expecting the signature of the function being called, not the `call` method which takes an object as the first parameter followed by the parameters of the function being called.